# Selected board depends on 'arduino' core (not installed)

Tags: linux, compilation-errors

When I load the Arduino IDE with `Board: Pololu A-Star 32U4` selected, I see:

```
The current selected board needs the core 'arduino:arduino' that is not installed.
```

I installed the board manually via [these instructions](https://github.com/pololu/a-star#manual-installation).

When verifying the initial empty sketch, I see:

```
Arduino: 1.8.8 (Linux), Board: "Pololu A-Star 32U4"

The current selected board needs the core 'arduino:arduino' that is not installed.
/usr/share/arduino/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /usr/share/arduino/hardware -hardware /home/ravi/Arduino/hardware -tools /usr/share/arduino/tools-builder -libraries /home/ravi/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=pololu:avr:a-star32U4 -ide-version=10808 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_299010 -warnings=none -build-cache /tmp/arduino_cache_842714 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -verbose /tmp/untitled689103723.tmp/sketch_feb05a/sketch_feb05a.ino

Selected board depends on 'arduino' core (not installed).

Error compiling for board Pololu A-Star 32U4.
```

How do I prevent this error and compile a sketch?

Comment: and what is the question? it is so that board packages can use other board packages and it is normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to install the boards package for:

```
Arduino AVR Boards
```

Under Tools -> Board -> Board Manager

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with the MySensors Sensebender Gateway but was not able to fix it by installing "Arduino AVR Boards". However, I *was* able to fix it by installing Arduino SAMD boards. This was a guess based on the fact that the package containing the actual SenseBender gateway board was called MySensors SAMD board. So just a note that this message apparently just means a board package dependency is mising, not necessarily the "Arduino AVR Boards" one.